# How to convert HVG(hue,sat,val) integer to Color rgb(r,g,b)integer in Java?

Tags: android

I have the integer pixel i got from get HVG(hue,sat,val), but i dont have any clue about how to convert it to RGB. For example,  HVG(hue,sat,val) to Color(0,200,0). Any tips?

Comment: could you point out where you are getting get.HVG() class from. I couldnot find it.

Answer (score 1):

`android.graphics.Color.HSVToColor()` will convert hue saturation and value into the packed RGB format used internally by the `Color` class.

Given an `int` in this format you can extract values for red, green, blue and alpha using methods of the `Color` class.